# Blackberry10 application installing

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi friends I am new to blackberry10 development. I am developing an application using HTML 5. I can run the application in Ripple Emulator. And with this i have created the bar file. But how can I install this application into my device. When I try this with command promt it show error as

```
Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
Info: Action: Install and Launch
Info: File size: 1118370
Info: Installing sampleapp.testRel_sampleapp__42572c37...
Info: Processing 1118370 bytes
actual_dname::
actual_id::
actual_version::
result::failure 881 required signatures missing (RDK, AUTHOR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the same issues when I wrote my first WebWorks app. Followed all the instructions in the guides and still had the same problem. Looked like the app is not deployed /launched in a debug mode.

So here is my solution:

Under the Ripple, on the right-hand side, there is the "Build" tab (or toolbox) - choose "Settings". A dialog will pop-up. There check the check-box "Enable Remote Web Inspector" and close the dialog.

Now just hit the "Package & Launch" button.

Should work.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you already have the signing keys set up, because you have the Dev Alpha.

Create a debug token with

```
blackberry-debugtokenrequest -storepass *yourkeypass* -devicepin *yourpin* d:\*yourfile*.bar
```

upload it to the device with

```
blackberry-deploy -installDebugToken d:\*yourfile*.bar -device *yourdeviceip* -password *yourdevicepass*
```

After this, place *yourfile*.bar in the main sdk folder, together with bbwp, and rename it as **debugtoken.bar**

**Enable remote web debugging** and now it works!